# What is a word that means religion adapted from history?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have seen this word before on Wikipedia. Usage would be something like

Christians may believe in the story of Noah's Ark; but modern scholars have a _______ interpretation. Noah's Ark may have been a real flood that happened in 1000BC. Or something like this.

Comment: What's wrong with _historical_?

Comment: I'm looking Maybe my example doesn't capture the specificity of the word. Every religion is "historical" to some extent. This word means that followers took a historical event, and they turn it into religious myth by adding the supernatural.

Answer (score 1):

Found the word: Euhemerism. The theory that mythology is derived from history.

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/euhemerism)
- [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/euhemerism?s=t)

You may downvote me now, but once this post is euhemerized I will be worshiped as a Stack Exchange deity; a Jon Skeet.